# Change color of CSS shape created by :after pseudo-element as its parent?

Tags: css, css-shapes

I have some HTML and CSS that display "text message" bubbles.  To create the bubble, a CSS class `.bub` is used.  Then, using `.bub:after`, the triangle is built.

I'm having a hard time changing the color of the CSS shape created by `:after` pseudo element according to its parent color.

### Goal:

To change the *color* of triangle which is created by `div:after` pseudo element. There will be a lot colors, so writing different classes for each color will be too cumbersome.

Here is the simplified CSS and HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <div id="container">
  <head>
  <style> 

.bub {
  width: 275px;
  display: table-cell;
  position:relative;
  padding:10px;
  margin:1em 0 3em;
  color:#fff;
  background:#075698;
  -webkit-border-radius:10px;
  -moz-border-radius:10px;
  border-radius:10px;
}

.bub:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-20px; 
  left:50px; /* controls horizontal position */
  border-width:20px 0 0 20px; /* vary these values to change the angle of the vertex */
  border-style:solid;
  /* reduce the damage in FF3.0 */
  display:block;
  width:0;
}

.bub.left {
  left: -100px;
}

.bub.left:after {
  top:16px;
  left:-40px; /* value = - border-left-width - border-right-width */
  bottom:auto;
  border-width:10px 40px 0 0; /* vary these values to change the angle of the vertex */
  border-color: transparent #333;
}

body {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  font:1em/1.4 Cambria, Georgia, sans-serif;
  color:#333;
  background:#fff;
}

#container {
  width:275px;
  padding:0 0 50px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
  border-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background: green;
  border-color: green;
}

.red {
  background: red;
  border-color: red;
}
    
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="content">
      <br><br>
      <div class="bub left blue">Test 1</div>
      <br>
      <div class="bub left green">Test 2</div>
      <br>
      <div class="bub left red">Test 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just use `color` property. But if they don't have any content (`content:''`) you won't see anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean to change the color of the shapes are created by [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3aafter) pseudo element;

Since you have set the [`border-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-color) property on each `.bub` element, you could simply use `inherit` value for the `:after` pseudo element as follow:

```css
.bub.left:after {
  border-color: transparent inherit;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/pahebezi/1/edit)**.

From the **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit)**:

> The inherit CSS-value causes the element for which it is specified to
>   take the computed value of the property from its parent element. It is
>   allowed on every CSS property.

Comment: Super awesome sir! Thank you. I applied in project and it worked great.

Comment: @user3425949 Don't mention it. I'm glad that I could help :)